Questions with watched tags are no longer highlighted on home page after redesign
The SO home page used to highlight a question when a question matched one of my watched tags.
Here is an example of what this used to look like:

This is the current home page behavior. Although numpy is one of my watched tags, the post is not highlighted, and the eye icon is not shown next to the tag.

This lack of highlighting makes it harder to find questions where I have expertise in the topic. Please restore the old highlighting behavior from before the redesign.
(Note: this question is different from Watched Tags is no longer accessible from the home page as that concerns whether the watched tags widget is shown on browsers which have small viewports.)

I remember the same thing happened during the previous redesign as well. Hopefully it will be fixed as swiftly as last time.

As I understand it, the new home page only shows questions in your watched tags, so there's no need to highlight them.

@Barmar For me, the front page includes questions that do not match any of my watched tags. For example, the first question on my front page is this question, and none of the tags on the question are part of my watched tags.

Can confirm that what Nick reported (questions that do not match watched tags) happens for me as well. @Barmar

It says it's "Based on your viewing history and watched tags." I'd still like the highlighting back, or an option to turn it back on.

Currently nothing about which questions are shown has changed, it's still using the same algorithm according to staff, no matter what the description says.

Second @NickODell here. The "Home" page is not near close to what I've use to. And the highlight is very important as it helps us filter through questions that we are not gonna look. Right now, I checked the first 10 posts on my home page, out them 7 does not have any of my tags, this is a small sample, I Know but 70% is too much outside of "Interested for you"

@JorgeCampos similar to you I had 4/10 irrelevant on the home page once. More recently, I counted all and 50/98 questions on the page were irrelevant to me.

Same here, annoying. I want the old behavior back...

The latest home page revision is a dumpster fire. I don't buy the "we didn't change which questions are shown" argument at all. Now, well over 90% of those questions are irrelevant to me, and I haven't changed my watched or ignored tags

I used to have some lists for tags that were related, and that filter would show me questions with any of those tags, for example for iOS I would have the swift, ios, objective-c tags under one of these lists. That behavior is now completely gone, and without the highlighting I don't want to spend 10 minutes looking for my followed tags... that's why I'm following them, you may want to show me 2-3 somewhat related questions but the vast majority should be of those watched tags...

@Frakcool you can find your custom filters on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Ah they moved those... @VLAZ thanks

I have "solved" this problem by switching to viewing questions on a custom filter to find questions to answer. I would appreciate having the watched tags highlight back - sometimes a question doesn't match any of my tags, but it is still interesting. I would like to use the home page for this, but it doesn't find enough questions from my watched tags to be useful for this.

The restoration is absolutely needed for older users and those that are visually challenged. Trying to pick through little tags to find relevant questions just leaves me with a headache. I've resorted to using https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest, but the number of displayed questions is less than the home page, and the button on the top-left to reload the page is now worthless. Please restore this lost functionality, it was appreciated and it is greatly needed. The new main page is simply unusable without it.

I like how the comment saying "Hopefully it will be fixed as swiftly as last time" was posted over 6 weeks ago. Really valuing the community as usual, SE Inc.
